# modal no se cierra ni el botón de cancelar sirve

Tags: php

Tengo mi index.php, este código:

```html
<div id="editar" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Y en otro archivo editar.php tengo mi modal porque así lo necesito pero no se quiere cerrar y también el botón de cancelar no se cierra

```js
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Accion</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="cerrar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="editar" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="item_name">Accion:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion" value="<?php echo $accion; ?>">
              
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" name="update" id="btn-editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Cancelar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Según el segundo segmento de HTML, en esta linea `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion" value="<?php echo $accion; ?>">
        </div>` te hace falta cerrar un `</div>` y uno mas al terminar el último `<div>`

Comment: ya lo corregí como me dijiste y aun así no sale :(

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con Bootstrap o algún otro framework o librería? Deberías mencionarlo y poner la etiqueta si fuera preciso. Y deberías decir cómo se enlazan ambos archivos. De paso, yo te aconsejo tratar de prescindir de los modales, es algo que data de Windows 3 (años 90), desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario, los modales producen hoy día un impacto negativo (salvo muy contadas excepciones).